# jQuery select another element with certain class in same parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

let say i have this div

```
<div id='parent'>
  <button id='button'></button>
  <div id='child'>
     <div id='grandchild' class='lookAtMe'>
          Some JSON text
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wanted to give the #button an on click event that returned the text at #lookAtMe div, specific to the div whom it shares parent/grandparent (in this case, the #parent div)

I tried using:

```
 $("#button").on("click",function(){
     var ReturnedText = $(this).parent(".lookAtMe").text();
     console.log(RetrunedText);
 });
```

But the console log would retruned (empty string).

Where did i do wrong? please help. Thankyou very much.

Comment: The button doesn't have a parent with class lookAtMe, it has a div with id parent as it's parent. Try $(this).parent().find('.lookAtMe').text();

Comment: You don't even need `parent`... `$(this).next().find('.lookAtMe').text()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is n o parent with that class. You need `find()`.

Actually you need to write

```
 var ReturnedText = $(this).parent().find(".lookAtMe").text();
```

---

```js
 $("#button").on("click",function(){
     var ReturnedText = $(this).parent().find(".lookAtMe").text();
     console.log(ReturnedText);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'>
  <button id='button'></button>
  <div id='child'>
     <div id='grandchild' class='lookAtMe'>
          Some JSON text
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah yes i see, seems like i have miss understanding. I tough the parent() arguments used to select something amon the parent's childern, so it actually used to specify the parents that we need to select. I see now. Thank you. I've tried the code and it worked very well.